# $C$-parity in $\pi^0\pi^+\pi^-$ system

Tags: conservation-laws, standard-model, parity, pions, charge-conjugation

I'm studying the conservation of the quantum number in the decay $\omega^0\rightarrow\pi^0\pi^+\pi^-$. Since

$P(\omega^0)=-1$

and

$P(\pi^0\pi^+\pi^-)=P(\pi^0)P(\pi^+)P(\pi^-)(-1)^{L_{+-}}(-1)^{L_{(+-)0}}=(-1)(-1)^{L_{+-}}(-1)^{L_{(+-)0}}$

To conserve parity $L_{+-}=L_{(+-)0}=1$

But to conserve C-parity

$C(\omega^0)=-1$

and

$C(\pi^0\pi^+\pi^-)=C(\pi^0)C(\pi^+\pi^-)(-1)^{L_{(+-)0}}=(-1)^{L_{(+-)0}}(-1)^{L_{+-}}$

since $C(\pi^0)=1$. Therefore if $L_{+-}=L_{(+-)0}=1$, C-parity is not conserved.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your would-be inconsistency (its a strong decay!) is the angular momentum factor you mysteriously inserted in the formula composing *C*s.

Composing parity entails the spherical harmonics whose *p*-waves have negative parity, and they are two of them, as you soundly determined. (In fact, as a mental prop, you may consider the decay as a sequence, $\omega\to \rho^0\pi^0\to 3\pi$, the last step of which is also *p*-wave. Recall $J^{PC}: ~~~\omega ~~1^{--}; ~~ \rho^0 ~~1^{--}; ~~ \pi^0 ~~O^{-+}$.  )

But the composition of the two meaningful (neutral particle) *C*s is
$$
C(\omega)= C(\rho^0)C(\pi^0)= (-)(+)= (-), 
$$
consistent. Recall, $C(\rho^0)\equiv C(\pi^+\pi^-)$, as the $\rho^0$ is a notional placeholder for the $\pi^+\pi^-$ p-wave eigenstate of C. There is no notional charge conjugation inserting the relative angular momentum $L_{(+-)0}$ between two charged particle constituents here.

---

*Edit on comment* : It is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... The WP point is correct for the C of a particle-antiparticle pair, and the $L_{+-}$ reminds you of the antisymmetry you *already* incorporated into the  $C=-$  of the ***placeholder*** $\rho^0$, which I put in for $\pi^+\pi^-$, to focus your thinking; nobody claimed you have to go through this channel; only that it easily summarizes the math.

- But there is *no* such  $(-)^L$ factor, as you wrongly inferred, for combining two neutral particles with well-defined C!

So, $L_{(+-)0}$ cannot and should not appear in the total C formula  that you invented out of whole cloth: it is pointless and wrong. Most good texts explain this.

Comment: I still don't understand. First, PDG doesn't specify the intermediate state with $\rho^0$ and I'm interested in the final state, not in the intermediate. Secondly, $\pi^+$ and $\pi^-$ are charged particles, so their c-parity is not defined, but when we consider the system of them, a term $(-1)^L$ apperas according to Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_parity . I just tried to follow the same argument.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's  clear ;)